# How to get child element in each loop if already bind 'this' to class in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to access child element in each loop. How to get child element in this ES6 class?

```
class helloClass {
  constructor(containerDivId) {

      $(‘#’ + containerDivId).children().each(function(index) { 
        // ‘this’ is not child element anymore.
        let child = $(this);       // Wrong.
        this.helloFunc();          // ok.
      }.bind(this));
  }

  helloFunc() {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried to have the **each(i,e)**
The e will be your object reference and the i will be the index